# BASH: error message does not get redirected to file

Tags: bash, redirect, io-redirection

I have a bash script that simply calls different calls and redirect stdout and stderr outputs to different files.

I've done this:

```
command 1> datafile 2>> errorfile
```

However, when the command is erroneous (e.g. wrong username and password combination given as arguments), the error message does not get redirected to the errorfile. I still see the error message on my screen when I run this script. For instance, the error message indicates that I provided a wrong combination of username and password.

What am I doing wrong?
I thought I should see no output on screen because I'm redirecting both stdout and stderr to files.

Comment: That actually works fine for me. I created foo but not bar, and ran `ls foo bar 1> data 2>> error` and got the desired results. What version of bash are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the program isn't writing to stderr, but directly opening /dev/tty to communicate with the user? This approach is fairly common when it comes to password interaction: software wants to make sure password prompts get "through" to the user despite any redirections.

If this is the case, you need pseudo-terminal trickery to arrange output to end up in a file.

If you don't have the source of the software, you can use strace/truss to find out what the program is really doing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? The question was asked more than a year ago, so maybe you better ask a new, specific question.

Comment: Ok, please see if you have an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056075/module-program-directly-writes-to-stderr-making-redirection-hard

Answer (score -1):

Your redirection command is wrong. With bash, try this:

```
$ cat redir.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Hello stdout\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello stderr\n");
}
$ ./redir > txt 2>&1
$ cat txt
Hello stderr
Hello stdout
$
```

The '2>&1' is key to also capture stderr.

Comment: A clearer version of your suggestion: `command > datafile 2>&1 >> errorfile`

Comment: @bcat: I stand corrected.  I mis-read the question -- I usually want stdout and stderr in the same file, which is what I showed.  Which is not what was asked.  Oops.

Comment: @Jefromi: if I do whatever you stated, datafile gets NOTHING. That's why I changed the command as above (my question).

Comment: @bLee: Martin v. Löwis' answer sounds most likely then. I was just suspicious of the 2>> shorthand (for no good reason, really).

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have an extra '>' in your stderr redirection.  Try:

```
command 1> datafile 2> errorfile
```

Edit:  As was pointed out in the comments, 2>> redirects stderr, appending to the file, whereas 2> overwrites the file.

I'm keeping this answer in place for reference purposes.

Comment: well, it was for "append". If I have >, then new errorfile will get created each time.

Comment: @bLee:  Doh!  You're right.  That's what I get for answering on my way out of the office.  Will edit.