# How to redirect a program that writes to tty?

Tags: bash, redirect, stderr, pty

This is the un-redirected output (if you don't know what `module` is, it doesn't matter much):

```
$ module help null

----------- Module Specific Help for 'null' -----------------------

        This module does absolutely nothing.
        It's meant simply as a place holder in your
        dot file initialization.

        Version 3.2.6
```

Suppose I'd like to redirect that to a file....

```
$ module help null > aaa.txt 

----------- Module Specific Help for 'null' -----------------------

        This module does absolutely nothing.
        It's meant simply as a place holder in your
        dot file initialization.

        Version 3.2.6

$ cat aaa.txt
$
```

Well, it must be on the `stderr`

```
$ module help null 2> aaa.txt 
        This module does absolutely nothing.
        It's meant simply as a place holder in your
        dot file initialization.

        Version 3.2.6

$ cat aaa.txt 

----------- Module Specific Help for 'null' -----------------------
$
```

Hey! It is resetting my redirect. This is really annoying, and I have two questions:

1. How can I achieve what I want, namely redirecting everything into my file
2. Why are they doing such a weird thing?

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343471/bash-error-message-does-not-get-redirected-to-file) related question.

EDIT: somebody asked in a comment, so some details. This is on AIX 5.3 at 64 bits. I have python 2.6.5 almost fully available. I have both gcc 4.1.1 and gcc 4.5.1 but not many libraries to link them against (the util-linux-ng library, which contains the script version mentioned in an answer fails to compile for the getopt part). I also have several version of IBM XL compiler xlc.
The reason why I didn't specify in the first place is that I was hoping in some shell tricks, maybe with exec, not in an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering the second question first: as a design choice, module is an eval and they took the (questionable) choice to use stderr/tty instead of stdout/stderr to keep their side of the design easier. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=b72feacd0807291116h6464db1ek7b430edef70ece69%40mail.gmail.com).

My solution, since I couldn't use any of the other recommended tools (e.g. script, expect) is the following python mini-wrapper:

```
import pty, os

pid, fd = pty.fork()
if pid == 0: # In the child process execute another command
    os.execv('./my-progr', [''])
    print "Execv never returns :-)"
else:
    while True:
        try:
            print os.read(fd,65536),
        except OSError:
            break
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
script -q -c 'module help null' /dev/null > aaa.txt
```

This works in a shell script (non-interactively) using

```
$ script --version
script (util-linux-ng 2.16)
```

You may also be able to use `expect`.

Also see: [Catching a direct redirect to /dev/tty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307006/catching-a-direct-redirect-to-dev-tty).

Comment: On MacOS 13.5, `script` does not accept `-c`. Instead, pass the command after the file:
```
script -q /dev/null module help null > aaa.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `module` is writing to `/dev/tty`, which is always the console associated with the process. If so, then I don't think you can do anything about it. Typically, this is done to guarantee that the person sees the message (assuming that the program was invoked interactively).

Comment: Well, the problem is the program is *not* invoked interactively. And `script` is a workaround that works, but (at least the version I have) works only interactively

Comment: My recommendation is then to get a version of script that does support -c.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy at all, on this platform (AIX). I'm trying but I guess it would be too much effort. Investigating expect too.

Comment: Then you should specify your limitations in your question. Can you compile C code, for example? Do you have Python available?